# TAdvEdit copy to clipboard

Tags: delphi

I want to copy `TAdvEdit.Text` to clipboard.

I tried:

```
procedure TFormMain.btnCopyToCbTestNameClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  edtTestName.CopyToClipboard;
  ShowMessage('Test name copied to clipboard.');
end;
```

It does not give an error, but when i press the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>, nothing gets pasted.

Comment: Did you ask TMS via their support forums?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [**CopyToClipboard**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.StdCtrls.TCustomEdit.CopyToClipboard) method copies only selected text. My best guess is that you have selected no text in your control. Try to select some before calling it. For example, to select the whole text:

```
procedure TFormMain.btnCopyToCbTestNameClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  edtTestName.SelectAll;
  edtTestName.CopyToClipboard;
end;
```

That applies to VCL edit control so as to **TAdvEdit**.